# Need help with insects on bottle gourd leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pests

Some of my bottle gourd leaves have thousands of tiny white spots like shown in the pic, and there are tiny brown insects crawling on them. The leaves look like they have sand along the veins.

What are these insects? And how can I treat the infected leaves?

They seem to be spreading on other leaves as well. Please help!

[image]